# Syntax Error with Full-Text Search

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

My query is below

```
select * from Test where contains (Description,'NEAR((method,system),3')
```

It shows an error in SQL server 2008.

```
Syntax error near '(' in the full-text search condition 'NEAR((method,system),3'
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Syntax error near '(' in the full-text search condition 'NEAR((method,system),3'

Comment: My Description column values as below 
 
Description: 
1)operation method and communication system thereof 
2)Method and system for zone-based capacity control 
 
There are two values in description field. 
If i give the values are method and system using near operator in sql server 2008 it will display result as "operation method and communication system thereof"... 
 
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't formatted your query correctly. Use this:

```
select * from Test where contains (Description,'NEAR((method,system),3)')
```

Comment: I have checked these query "select * from Test where contains (Description,'NEAR((method,system),3)')" but again it comes same error.

Comment: Error: Syntax error near '(' in the full-text search condition 'NEAR((method,system),3)'

Comment: @gunaa This answer is correct only if you have SQL Server 2012 installed. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the NEAR operator in such a way, you should upgrade to SQL Server 2012. This syntax isn't available in previous versions as it is new to the 2012 version.

If you compare the documentation on MSDN between the [2008 version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and the [2012 version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), you will see that the 2008 doesn't support the syntax.

Syntax for 2012:

```
<custom_proximity_term> ::= 
  NEAR ( 
     {
        { <simple_term> | <prefix_term> } [ ,…n ]
     |
        ( { <simple_term> | <prefix_term> } [ ,…n ] ) 
      [, <maximum_distance> [, <match_order> ] ]
     }
       ) 

      <maximum_distance> ::= { integer | MAX }
      <match_order> ::= { TRUE | FALSE }
```

Syntax for 2008:

```
<proximity_term> ::= 
     { <simple_term> | <prefix_term> } 
     { { NEAR | ~ }
     { <simple_term> | <prefix_term> } 
     } [ ...n ]
```